# Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition despite repartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I load a dataset

```
val data = sc.textFile("/home/kybe/Documents/datasets/img.csv",defp)
```

I want to put an index on this data thus

```
val nb = data.count.toInt
val tozip = sc.parallelize(1 to nb).repartition(data.getNumPartitions)

val res = tozip.zip(data)
```

Unfortunately i have the following error

```
Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition
```

How can i modify the number of element by partition if it is possible ?

Comment: I'm a beginner so maybe not the best solution but in theory one  could `zipWithIndex` on both RDD and then do a `join` (or left join or right join depending on how you wanna mix the two RDDs) using the index of the elements, another way would be to calculate the difference in length and fill the void with defaults, not sure how to do that with an RDD though.

Comment: I totally forget this great function ! Thank's
But i still don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: AFAIK I don't think that having the same number of partitions equals to having two RDD of the same length, I think `repartition` shuffles the partitions in your cluster, from the docs: `Reshuffle the data in the RDD randomly to create either more or fewer partitions and balance it across them. This always shuffles all data over the network.`, which, if I got the whole thing right, in your case doesn't make much sense if you then need to join (which cause another reshuffling).

Answer (score 11):

### Why it doesn't work?

The documentation for [zip()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#zip(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) states:

> Zips this RDD with another one, returning key-value pairs with the first element in each RDD, second element in each RDD, etc. Assumes that the two RDDs have the *same number of partitions* and the *same number of elements in each partition* (e.g. one was made through a map on the other).

So we need to make sure we meet 2 conditions:

- both RDDs have the same number of partitions
- respective partitions in those RDDs have exactly the same size

You are making sure that you will have the same number of partitions with `repartition()` but Spark doesn't guarantee that you will have the same distribution in each partition for each RDD.

### Why is that?

Because there are different types of RDDs and most of them have different partitioning strategies! For example:

- ParallelCollectionRDD is created when you parallelise a collection with `sc.parallelize(collection)` it will see how many partitions there should be, will check the size of the collection and calculate the `step` size. I.e. you have 15 elements in the list and want 4 partitions, first 3 will have 4 consecutive elements last one will have the remaining 3.
- HadoopRDD if I remember correctly, one partition per file block. Even though you are using a local file internally Spark first creates a this kind of RDD when you read a local file and then maps that RDD since that RDD is a pair RDD of `<Long, Text>` and you just want `String` :-)
- etc.etc.

In your example Spark internally does create different types of RDDs (`CoalescedRDD` and `ShuffledRDD`) while doing the repartitioning but I think you got the global idea that **different RDDs have different partitioning strategies** :-)

Notice that the last part of the `zip()` doc mentions the `map()` operation. This operation does not repartition as it's a **narrow** transformation data so **it would** guarantee both conditions.

### Solution

In this simple example as it was mentioned you can do simply `data.zipWithIndex`. If you need something more complicated then creating the new RDD for `zip()` should be created with `map()` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating an implicit helper like so

```
implicit class RichContext[T](rdd: RDD[T]) {
  def zipShuffle[A](other: RDD[A])(implicit kt: ClassTag[T], vt: ClassTag[A]): RDD[(T, A)] = {
    val otherKeyd: RDD[(Long, A)] = other.zipWithIndex().map { case (n, i) => i -> n }
    val thisKeyed: RDD[(Long, T)] = rdd.zipWithIndex().map { case (n, i) => i -> n }
    val joined                    = new PairRDDFunctions(thisKeyed).join(otherKeyd).map(_._2)
    joined
  }
}
```

Which can then be used like

```
val rdd1   = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3))
val rdd2   = sc.parallelize(Seq(2,4,6))
val zipped = rdd1.zipShuffle(rdd2) // Seq((1,2),(2,4),(3,6))
```

**NB:** Keep in mind that the `join` will cause a shuffle.

Comment: Join is in O(nm) with n and m size of collections compare to zip which is O(n) thus join is not suffisant for large data volume.

Answer (score 0):

The following provides a Python answer to this problem by defining a custom_zip method:
[Can only zip with RDD which has the same number of partitions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084368/can-only-zip-with-rdd-which-has-the-same-number-of-partitions-error)