# PySpark: How to concatenate two distinct dataframes?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have multiple dataframes that I need to concatenate together, row-wise. In pandas, we would typically write: `pd.concat([df1, df2])`.

This thread: [How to concatenate/append multiple Spark dataframes column wise in Pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320699/how-to-concatenate-append-multiple-spark-dataframes-column-wise-in-pyspark) appears close, but its respective answer:

```
    df1_schema = StructType([StructField("id",IntegerType()),StructField("name",StringType())])
    df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1, "sammy"),(2, "jill"),(3, "john")])
    df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1, schema=df1_schema)
    df2_schema = StructType([StructField("secNo",IntegerType()),StructField("city",StringType())])

    df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(101, "LA"),(102, "CA"),(103,"DC")])
    df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2, schema=df2_schema)

schema = StructType(df1.schema.fields + df2.schema.fields)
df1df2 = df1.rdd.zip(df2.rdd).map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1])
spark.createDataFrame(df1df2, schema).show()
```

Yields the following error when done on my data at scale: `Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition`

How can I join 2 or more data frames that are identical in row length but are otherwise independent of content (they share a similar repeating structure/order but contain no shared data)?

Example expected data looks like:

```
    +---+-----+        +-----+----+       +---+-----+-----+----+
    | id| name|        |secNo|city|       | id| name|secNo|city|
    +---+-----+        +-----+----+       +---+-----+-----+----+
    |  1|sammy|    +   |  101|  LA|   =>  |  1|sammy|  101|  LA|
    |  2| jill|        |  102|  CA|       |  2| jill|  102|  CA|
    |  3| john|        |  103|  DC|       |  3| john|  103|  DC|
    +---+-----+        +-----+----+       +---+-----+-----+----+
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? It looks you are trying to merge these 2 data frames by column (id, name, age, address) and to merge the column as single table, what is the key you are expecting the df to use?

Comment: spark (or sql) would require your dataframes to have a join-key in all dataframes that gets matched while merging the data. without that a cross join is performed. see doc on [`join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html) and [some examples](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/).

Comment: also, spark does not retain a sort order like pandas does. so, while pandas can merge on index, spark does not have anything without an `id` column.

Comment: I've updated the expected output; I am hoping to merge the tables but not using any key, a la how pandas handles it

Comment: The reason it doesn't work at scale is that the rdd has multiple partitions with varying number of records in each partition, and zip fails. A detailed answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36058718/19261326

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create unique IDs with

```
df1 = df1.withColumn("unique_id", expr("row_number() over (order by (select null))"))

df2 = df2.withColumn("unique_id", expr("row_number() over (order by (select null))"))
```

then, you can `left` join them

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("unique_id"), "left").drop("unique_id")
```

Final output looks like

```
+---+----+---+-------+
| id|name|age|address|
+---+----+---+-------+
|  1|   a|  7|      x|
|  2|   b|  8|      y|
|  3|   c|  9|      z|
+---+----+---+-------+
```

Comment: How do I use `Seq()`? PySpark is throwing an unrecognized error

Comment: df1.join(df2, df1.unique_id == df2.unique_id, "left")

Comment: `Seq()` is a scala construct. The answer works fine without `Seq`: `df1.join(df2, "unique_id", "left").drop("unique_id")`

Comment: How might I do this with 3 dataframes? `unique_id` becomes ambiguous in the `df1.join(df2...` output