# How to get intersection of each element of two nested lists in python?

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark, nested-lists

I'm working in pyspark environment and if I have **two nested lists** a and b,

```
a=[[1,2,3],[8,9,45,0,65],[3,7,23,88],[44,77,99,100,654]]
b=[[1,3,7],[0,9,67,22,45,8,11],[23,3],[100]]
```

and I want the intersection of these two in python

```
intersection_list=[[1,3],[8,9,45,0],[3,23],[100]]
```

and the final count of this be

```
list_count=[2,3,2,1]
```

how to get this results in pyspark?

I have tried

```
[[[n for n in a if n in b]for x in a]for y in b]
```

but this did't gave me required  **intersection_list**

Is there any way to do this with rdd also in pypark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[n for n in x if n in y] for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

However if the sublists are big this would be better:

```
[set(x).intersection(y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

(although the order of elements is lost)

Comment: This will work with lists but not with RDDs. You can adjust it using techniques I shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32084368/1560062

Comment: the below written code is throwing this error in pyspark

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[[1,2,3],[8,9,45,0,65],[3,7,23,88],[44,77,99,100,654]]
b=[[1,3,7],[0,9,67,22,45,8,11],[23,3],[100]]

intersection_list = [list(set(x) & set(y)) for x, y in zip(a,b)]

>> [[1, 3], [8, 9, 45, 0], [3, 23], [100]]

list_count = [ len(x) for x in intersection_list ]

>> [2, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: this code is throwing the given error in pyspark:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not callable